# Java draw triangle

Tags: java, rendering, render, draw

I have been using the following code to draw a rotated polygon:

```
public static void renderPoly(Graphics g, double cx, double cy, int sides, double radius, double rotation){
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    double deltaAngle = (Math.PI * 2) / sides;
    double angle;
    double lastX = cx + radius * Math.cos(0 - rotation);
    double lastY = cy + radius * Math.sin(0 - rotation);
    for(int n = 1; n <= sides; n++){
        angle = deltaAngle * n;
        double x = cx + radius * Math.cos(angle - rotation);
        double y = cx + radius * Math.cos(angle - rotation);
        g2d.drawLine((int)lastX, (int)lastY, (int)x, (int)y);
        lastX = x;
        lastY = y;
    };
};
```

Unfortunately, this is failing to work for me when I call it:

```
renderPoly(g, 15, 15, 3, 5, Math.toRadians(-90));
```

[image]

**What has gone wrong in my code?** Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is wrong

```
        double y = cx + radius * Math.cos(angle - rotation);
```

should be sin, no?

Comment: You might also want to check out this PolygonFactory class: http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/shape/PolygonFactory.java